# JAXB unmarshallling fail when runnin on WAS 7 (succeed on a standalone test)

Tags: websphere-7, jaxb2

JAXB unmarshallling fails when runnin on `WAS 7`  (succeed on a standalone test)

```
[21/11/12 16:47:55:690 CET] 00000025 DefaultMessag W org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer invokeErrorHandler Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
                                 java.lang.VerifyError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.<init>(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.ca.cib.zba.message.mt101.ObjectFactory.createMatherUnmarshaller(ObjectFactory.java:23)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.JAXB_Deserialization_Root_Stub.write(com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.JAXB_Deserialization_Root_Stub.java)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationStub.end(DeserializationStub.java:151)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationContext.endComplexType(DeserializationContext.java:673)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationContext.handleEndElementEvent(DeserializationContext.java:384)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.produceEndElementEvent(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:234)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.scanEndElement(DocumentScanner.java:2590)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.nextEvent(DocumentScanner.java:1289)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.parseDocumentEntity(DocumentScanner.java:1168)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.unmarshal(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:147)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:158)
    at com.ca.cib.zba.message.mt101.ZBAProcessingResultXMLTool.getZBAProcessingResult(ZBAProcessingResultXMLTool.java:52)
    at com.ca.cib.zba.message.mt101.listener.ListenerMT101.processMessage(ListenerMT101.java:80)
    at com.ca.cib.zba.message.mt101.listener.ListenerMT101.onMessage(ListenerMT101.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
```

It is `ObjectFactory.createMatherUnmarshaller` that fails when running on Websphere application server while it works fine on stand alone test

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "ZBAProcessingResult")
public JAXBElement<ZBAProcessingResult> createMatherUnmarshaller(ZBAProcessingResult zbaProcessingResult){
        return new JAXBElement<ZBAProcessingResult>(ZBAProcessingResult_QNAME, ZBAProcessingResult.class,null,zbaProcessingResult); 
    }
```

Comment: I should make it clear that, both application the marshalling one and the un-marshalling one run on the same WAS 7 (test environment is not what we will get in production). 
The problem remains!
However I put “parents last” for module and application on the Websphere Application Sever settings to prevent jar hell and class collision from one application to the others or from them to IBM’s.

Answer (score 0):

A solution as been found I used a ObjectFactory.java and it was apparently the evil origin (in the Websphere Application Server’s world). So I switch to using a jaxb.index containing my serialized classes’ name. And I changed my code to not use JAXBElement :

Comment: ZBAProcessingResult zbaProcessingResult = (ZBAProcessingResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputSource(new StringReader(zbaProcessingResultXML)));
  return zbaProcessingResult;

 }